# Problem with writing IDs to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown with names of project managers and a checkboxlist with names of team members. What I want to do is write the IDs of selections made from the dropdown and checkboxlist to the DB. I am using the following code, but only IDs from the checkboxlist are stored in the table. What can I do to store the ID from the dropdown simultaneously? Thanks for your help.

```
for (int i = 0; i < project_members.Items.Count; i++)
{

            if (project_members.Items[i].Selected)
            {


                SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
                param[0] = new SqlParameter("@member_id", SqlDbType.Int);
                param[0].Value = project_manager.SelectedValue;
                param[0].Value = project_members.Items[i].Value;


                for (int j = 0; j < param.Length; j++)
                {
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add(param[j]);
                }

                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd2.Parameters.Clear();

            }
}
```

Comment: Why do you set `param[0].Value` twice? The value of `project_manager.SelectedValue` is basically ignored ...

Comment: is there a One to many relation ship between Project manager and Team members.. can you show us the structure of database

Comment: Yes, there's a one to many relationship - that's why I'm using a dropdown for project manager selection and checkboxlist to select team members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create new parameters every loop iteration.

```
SqlParameter managerParameter = new SqlParameter("@manager_id", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd2.Parameters.Add(managerParameter);
managerParameter.Value = project_manager.SelectedValue;

SqlParameter memberParameter = new SqlParameter("@member_id", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd2.Parameters.Add(memberParameter);

cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

// For better performance in the loop, you could prepare the query:
cmd2.Prepare();
for (int i = 0; i < project_members.Items.Count; ++i)
{
    if (project_members.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        memberParameter = project_members.Items[i].Value;
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Note that I assumed that the selected mananger played a different role than the "normal" members. If the manager should be handled like any member, try that:

```
SqlParameter memberParameter = new SqlParameter("@member_id", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd2.Parameters.Add(memberParameter);

cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

// For better performance in the loop, you could prepare the query:
cmd2.Prepare();

memberParameter.Value = project_manager.SelectedValue;
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

for (int i = 0; i < project_members.Items.Count; ++i)
{
    if (project_members.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        memberParameter = project_members.Items[i].Value;
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with these lines:

```
param[0] = new SqlParameter("@member_id", SqlDbType.Int);
param[0].Value = project_manager.SelectedValue;
param[0].Value = project_members.Items[i].Value;
```

you are assigning `param[0]` with `project_manager.SelectedValue;` then you are overwriting it with `project_members.Items[i].Value;`

Comment: Thanks, I am using param[0] twice, because I want to write values to the same field in the table. How can I change that?

Comment: then you should do `+=` instead of = .Or more better like this  `param[0] =  project_manager.SelectedValue.Tostring() + project_members.Items[i].Value.ToString();`